# Python - Dataframes looping and executing the API Calls

Tags: python, json, dataframe

New to python and trying to execute series of API based on the output of previous API and in this process I am having a problem with the following issue.

I have some values in the dataframes, I want to loop through the dataframes based on a condition(all is greater than or equal to 1) and take the id(satisfying the condition) from the dataframes and execute an API URL

**DataFrame**

```
Index | id | all
0     | 1  | 1
1     | 2  | 0
2     | 3  | 5
3     | 4  | 2
4     | 5  | 0
5     | 6  | 0
6     | 7  | 3
7     | 8  | 4
```

**Code**

```
alert = '/alert'

for value in dataframe['all']:
    if value >= 1:
        for each in dataframe['id']:
            url1 = "https://mywebsite/new/"+str(each)+str(alert)
            response1 = requests.get(url=url1, headers=headers, params=querystring1).json()
            print(response1)
            print("New ID :" +str(each))
    else:
        print("No alerts id are :" +str(value))
```

The issue is I am getting the response but it is not going through the condition, it is displaying response for `id` 2 & 6 which has `all` value as 0 and the loop never breaks as well.

Could any one please let me know what mistake I am doing

Comment: what kind of object is this dataframe? Are you using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested loop here. 
Thus you are iterating through all values in `dataframe['id']` for every value in `dataframe['all']`.

You need to iterate through values in both `id` and `all` columns in one loop.

Comment: I did the following changes in the code   ```for value, each in dataframe[['all', 'id']]:
    if value >= 1:
        for each in dataframe['id']:
            url1 = "https://mywebsite/new/"+str(each)+str(alert)
            response1 = requests.get(url=url1, headers=headers, params=querystring1).json()
            print(response1)
            print("New ID :" +str(each))```  Getting error **too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

The following code worked for me.

```
for index, value in dataframe.iterrows():
    if value['all'] > 0:
        url1 = "https://mywebsite/new/"+str(value['id'])+str(alert)
        response1 = requests.get(url=url1, headers=headers, params=querystring1).json()
        print(response1)
        print("New ID :" +str(value['id']))
```